# Intellegencia urlrewriter is not working showing 404 page not found

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, iis-5

These are some extracts from my web.config file on development server. Intelligencia URL was fine but when  deployed on production(IIS 5 on both servers) it returns page not found(404 error) on every rewritten url except for one which has ~/(guid value).aspx/value (rewriiten url)  working

```
      <section name="rewriter" requirePermission="false" 
                                                                                               type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler, 
                        Intelligencia.UrlRewriter"/>
```

```
        <system.webServer>

            <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">


       <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule"/>


        </modules>

        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>

    <modules>
```

```
 </modules>
```

```
                 <add name="Elmah" path="elmah.axd" verb="POST,GET,HEAD"                      type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode"/>

     </handlers>
           </system.webServer>
            <httpModules>

         <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule,                        System.Web.Extensions,               Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral,                          PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
             <add                                                                                                  type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule,Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" 
        name="UrlRewriter"/>
      <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah"/>

      </httpModules>

<rewriter>
    <rewrite url="~/myone/tags/(.+)" to="~/myone/tagpage.aspx?tag=$1"/>
```

```
  <add  verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd"     type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>


          <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory,               Elmah"/>

    </httpHandlers>
```

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar rule that uses (.*) instead of (.+). Might work for you (if that's acceptable for your use cases).

Answer (score 0):

1. Go Run -> inetmgr -> select your website -> right click on properties and select Configuration.
2. Select C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll in executables and in extension place.
3. Uncheck "VERIFY THAT FILE EXISTS."